# How to lower one number when the other rises?

Tags: javascript, processing, correlation, generative-art

I take a value from the mouse (`mouseX`) position in Processing, as this value gets higher, I want the amount of boxes that are rendered to lower in steps of 5 (`rotStep`).

I did a lot of reading and found out the method I should use is called 'Negative correlation' or at least I think it is. I have never had high-grade math so I'm pretty much in the dark here. Maybe there is a function that already exists to do this. After a lot of googling I came in here to ask.

Tried dividing the `mouseX` input by itself and some other random sums but it seems this might be more complicated than I anticipated.

I am trying to get into generative art generation and could use a hint to get further with my attempt of rendering more boxes (quads) as the `mouseX` value lowers.

```java
void setup() {
  pixelDensity(displayDensity());
  size(500, 500);
  background(0);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
  background(0);
  mouseX= constrain(mouseX, 1, width);
  mouseY= constrain(mouseY, 1, height);

  float rotationMax = 90;
  float rotStep = (mouseX/15)+5;

  //I need to add a negative correlation so the number
  //of squares lowers as the mouseX position gets higher
  //and all this in steps of 5


  float quadSize = mouseX;
  float qs = quadSize;

  for (float i=0; i<rotationMax; i+=rotStep) {
    float deg = rotStep;
    float rad = radians(deg);
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(1);
    rotate(rad);
    quad(-qs, -qs, qs, -qs, qs, qs, -qs, qs);
  }
}
```

The `rotStep` variable should decrease when the `mouseX` variable increases and vice versa. The variable `rotStep` should also increase or decrease in steps of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice I can give you is to get out a piece of paper and a pencil, and draw a table of mouse positions and the number of boxes you want. It might look like this:

```
mouseX  boxes
---------------
0      | 50
100    | 40
200    | 30
300    | 20
400    | 10
500    | 0
```

This is just an example, so your numbers would probably be different. But the idea is to have a general mapping of `mouseX` to the number of boxes you want to draw.

Once you have that, then you can try to find an equation that gets you from `mouseX` to your box count. That might be a single equation, or it might involve `if` statements to bucket values together.

You can get a "negative correlation" by subtracting from the maximum possible value, or by using `mouseX` as a divisor.

```
float reverseMouseX = width - mouseX;
float inverseMouseX = 1 / mouseX;
```

For both of these approaches, as `mouseX` increases, the value of the variable will decrease. Then you can use these values in your equation or in your `if` statement logic.

To get to the example table I showed above, I might do something like this:

```
int boxes = (width - mouseX) / 10;
```

This is a general approach, but you can apply it to your goal to come up with a specific solution.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your hints, with the reverseMouseX I have managed to get the negative correlation. Right now I am trying to get the steps right. I have done a division on the output of rotational steps and 'floored' the result. Then the result multiplicated by 5 to get a count going up in steps of 5 and this works well. Now I'm running into yet another unwanted result as the generated boxes only start to generate when the number is very low and every time I change my formula to compensate, the script crashes. I think I need a nights rest to think about it. Thanks for your advice and edit so far!

Comment: @Marinus You're welcome. I suggest putting together a [mcve] of your new problem and posting it in its own question. Good luck!

Comment: Just t let you know, this is the result in three posts of what I managed to do with your help. So thanks a lot! https://twitter.com/ABlahstar84/status/1165169185632280576